# Edittext : Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed

Tags: java, android, input, dialog

XML.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/WhiteTextInputLayout"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:id="@+id/txDept"
                    android:textColorHint="#FFF"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/input_department"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                        android:editable="false"
                        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_department"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:hint="Department"/>
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Java.file

```
etDepartment.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                chooseDepartment();
                return true;
            }
        });

void chooseDepartment(){

        final CharSequence[] items = {AUTO,CIVIL,CSC,EEE,ECE,EIE,ETE,IT,MBA,MCA,MECH};
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUp.this);
        builder.setTitle("Choose your Department");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                etDepartment.setText(items[which]);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.show();

    }
```

When a user clicks the item displayed in that list dialog..Edittext will set that text.

But now its unable to close the dialog with a single click.After twice or thrice clicks only, the dialog will close.

An error that I saw in logcat:

> W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input
>   event receiver has already been disposed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This dialog is opening multiple times because of multiple actions you will get in `OnTouchListener`, so try to do operation only on `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`,

Try this,

```
etDepartment.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    chooseDepartment();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```